# how to use strcopy in c++

Tags: c++, copy, char

in c++ , i have a file named "Student.h"

```
class LinkedList {
private: 

class Student {
public:

    int stId;
    char stName [20];
    char stMajor[20];
    double stAverage;
    Student * next;

    Student() {
        next = 0;
    }

    Student(int stId, char stName [20], char stMajor[20], double stAverage) {
        this.stId = stId;
        strcopy(this.stName, stName); // there is error here !
        strcopy(this.stMajor, stMajor);
        this.stAverage = stAverage;
    }
```

what should i do ?!

Comment: `strcopy()`? `strcpy()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` is a pointer in C++, not a reference as in Java. Plus what you need is `strcpy()` not `strcopy()`

Try this

```
    strcpy(this->stName, stName); 
    strcpy(this->stMajor, stMajor);
```

P.S : In C++ it is always recommended to prefer `std::string` over C-style arrays

A much cleaner version of your code would be something like this

```
struct Student {

    int stId;
    std::string stName;
    std::string stMajor;
    double stAverage;
    Student * next;

    Student():stId(),stAverage(),next()//prefer initialization-list to assignment
    {
    }

    Student(int stId, const std::string &stName, const std::string &stMajor, double stAverage){
      this->stId = stId,
      this->stName = stName ,
      this->stMajor = stMajor,
      this->stAverage = stAverage;          
    }
};
```

Comment: @Prasoon: please, don't teach people to pass `std::string` by value, as in your (current) `std::string stMajor`. Please make that `std::string const& stMajor`. Bad habits are difficult to get rid of, best to start with good habits :-)

Comment: @soad: you're putting down work to learn C++, and you have no time to learn? well, then you're screwed.

Comment: yeah , it's a homework , the prof just till us it's like c , and to go on !

Comment: If you don't have time to learn when doing homework, when *will* you have time to work? On the job? In your sleep, perhaps? Homework is *for* learning, you know.

Comment: @Alf: since he's copying the string anyway, passing by value makes perfect sense. Just swap it into place then.

Comment: @jalf: no it does not make perfect sense to needlessly do things in "smart" ways. On the contrary: it does not make sense at all. Especially when the "smart" way, as in this case, doesn't achieve anything except confusion.

Answer (score 2):

> what should i do ?!

You should:

- use `std::string` instead of raw arrays.
- use `std::list` instead of inventing your own (except for purpose of learning about linked lists).
- not indicate array sizes in formal arguments, like your `char stName [20]`; the formal argument type does not retain the size information, it just devolves to a pointer type.
- generally avoid using `this` directly.
- generally use initializer lists instead of assignments in the constructor body.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the `strcpy` function (without **o**).

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer, not a reference, so you have to use pointer dereferencing operators:

```
    strcpy(this->stName, stName);
```

or

```
    strcpy((*this).stName, stName);
```

Moreover, I don't recommend using `char[20]` as a datatype for student names - that is very prone to buffer overflow errors. You could overcome this by using `strncpy`

```
    strcpy(this->stName, stName, 19);
    this->stName[20]=0;
```

But the most convenient way is using `std::string`, which can be conveniently copied by assignment.

And last, if you chose some convention for member variable names, you could just refer to them without `this`. Eg:

```
class Student {
public:

    std::string m_stName;

...
    Student(int stId, std::string stName, ...) {
         m_stName=stName;
```

or even (using initializers):

```
Student(int stId, std::string stName, ...) : m_stName(stName) {
     m_stName=stName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use `std::string`?

```
string s1, s2 = "example";
s1 = s2;
```

Anyway, the problem is that in C++ `this` returns a *pointer*, therefore `this.stId` is wrong, the correct form would be `this->stId`, or alternatively `(*this).stId`.